# How to insert a record in lambda expression and possible way to shorten the length of code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, lambda

```
private void SaveNewLogsheet01Record()
        {
            try
            {
                Logsheet01 Header = new Logsheet01();
                Header.DrNO = drNO.Text;
                Header.DocDate = dtPicker.Value;  
                Header.RecNum = RecNum.Value;  
                Header.DocuTitle = DocumentHeader.Text;  

                SaveRec01(Header);                    
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
 }

     private void SaveNewLogsheet02Record()
        {
            try
            {
                Logsheet02 Details = new Logsheet02();
                Details.RecNum = RecNum.Value;
                Details.DataFile01 = GlobalVar.DataRec01;                        
                Details.DataFile02 = GlobalVar.DataRec02;                        
                Details.DataFile03 = GlobalVar.DataRec03;                        
                Details.UserName = GlobalVar.UserInfo;                        

                SaveRec02(Details);                    
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
 }

private void SaveRec01(Logsheet01 Header) <-- is this necessary in c#?
    {
        try
        {
            using (DBDataContext DB = new DBDataContext()) 
            {
                DB.Delivery_HeaderRECs.InsertOnSubmit(Header);
                DB.SubmitChanges();
                DB.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

private void SaveRec02(Logsheet02 Header)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DBDataContext DB = new DBDataContext()) 
            {
                DB.Logsheet0.InsertOnSubmit(Header);
                DB.SubmitChanges();
                DB.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

> i just want to find a new way on how to insert a
>   record on database make my codes cleaner and shorter now if i have a
>   form with multiple insert on tables ex.: Tables like "Logsheet01" and
>   "Logsheet02" , "Logsheet03" and i want my codes to be shorten. is
>   there a way i can put in the saveRec01 Function into one function for
>   3 tables?

---

is there a way i could make like this:

```
private void SaveRec01(Logsheet01 Header)
    {
        if(Saving == "Logsheet01") {
           using(DBDatacontex DB = new DBDatacontex) {
               DB.Logsheet01.InsertOnSubmit(Header);
               DB.SubmitChanges();
               DB.Connection.Close();
           }
        }elseif (Saving == "Logsheet02") {
           using(DBDatacontex DB = new DBDatacontex) {
               DB.Logsheet02.InsertOnSubmit(Header);
               DB.SubmitChanges();
               DB.Connection.Close();
           }
        } //etc..
    }
```

or maybe a new lambda expression of insert a record list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to get rid of the repetitive code and only specify the "meat" of the database operation each time, you can move all your boilerplate code into a method which accepts an `Action` that defines the variable component of your operation like so:

```
// Wrapper for our database operation.
private void PerformDbOperationAndSubmit(Action<DBDataContext> action)
{
    using (DBDataContext DB = new DBDataContext()) 
    {
        // Invoke our arbitrary action over the data context.
        action(DB);

        DB.SubmitChanges();
        DB.Connection.Close();
    }
}

// Object creation (modified for the sake of brevity).
private void SaveNewLogsheet01Record()
{
    Logsheet01 Header = new Logsheet01();

    // Fill Header properties here.

    PerformDbOperationAndSubmit(dx => dx.Delivery_HeaderRECs.InsertOnSubmit(Header));                    
}

private void SaveNewLogsheet02Record()
{
    Logsheet02 Details = new Logsheet02();

    // Fill Details properties here.

    PerformDbOperationAndSubmit(dx => dx.Logsheet0.InsertOnSubmit(Details));                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
Logsheet01 Header = new Logsheet01({     
  DrNO = drNO.Text,
  DocDate = dtPicker.Value,
  RecNum = RecNum.Value,
  DocuTitle = DocumentHeader.Text  
 });


Header.SaveRecord();
```

Create a function like this one:

```
private void SaveRecord()

{
         using(DBDatacontex DB = new DBDatacontex) {
         //I used this because the SaveRecord function is in the same class as the object used to create the record
         DB.Delivery_HeaderRECs.InsertOnSubmit(this);
         DB.SubmitChanges(); }


}
```

}